# Showing Viewpager's specific fragment page

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I want to to open viewpager's specific fragment in onCreateView..How can I do it..My application always start position 0..But i must open for example 3-page..When I open My app third element of the viewpager must be shown..How ca i do it?

```
private void setupViewpager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragement(new Fragment_home1());
    adapter.addFragement(new Fragment_home2());
    adapter.addFragement(new Fragment_home3());
    adapter.addFragement(new Fragment_home4());
    adapter.addFragement(new Fragment_home5());
    adapter.addFragement(new Fragment_home6());
    adapter.addFragement(new Fragment_home7());

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private void setupTabName() {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setText(R.string.hammasi);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setText(R.string.amalgaOshirish);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setText(R.string.imzolash);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setText(R.string.tasdiqlash);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(4).setText(R.string.malumot);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(5).setText(R.string.rezolutsiya);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(6).setText(R.string.toldirishga);

}

      private class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragement(Fragment fragment) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by this way: `viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);`.

Comment: Did you do it after setting adapter?

Comment: Keep a practice of marking the answer as accepted if it has solved your concern so that others can follow it too.

Answer (score 0):

It's Full Answer Its work For me

**viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);**

first setAdapter then use

**viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);**